# Cron job from application or external server

Tags: java, spring-boot, server, gemfire, pcf

I am working on an application which is deployed in pcf and we are using caching mechanism. We want to implement a batch job which will purge the data from cache region.

I want get some suggestions on below:

1. should i include this batch job in the same application so that it uses the same server to run the batch jobs?
2. or should i create a new server for running these batch jobs?

Just want to see how the performance of the current application will be impacted, if we run the batch job from the same server. Just want to see the advantages and disadvantages for the same..

TIA

Comment: For me personally I almost always use a separate server to run cron jobs across all of our machines. Since I work at a smaller company that really only uses a single Dev and multiple Prod boxes it made the most sense to create a "maintenance" box. Once again our company does something similar where we pull and do clean up on a few sql servers. Instead of running very memory intense SQL queries we write 1 query and let the standalone server use its main memory to run the computations. Less resource intense on the prod boxes

Comment: If you're using GemFire, you have different options: the easiest one would be to write a simple [Function](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/910/geode/developing/function_exec/chapter_overview.html) that clears the `Region` and automatically execute it using the `Spring Task Execution and Scheduling` mechanism. Another one, which doesn't require any custom code, would be to set up [Data Expiration](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/910/geode/developing/expiration/configuring_data_expiration.html) for the `Region` so the entries get automatically deleted after some configurable time.